# Добавление через цикл в объект get\set свойство

Tags: javascript, ооп

Как через цикл добавить свойство, проходя по массиву объектов, что бы установить каждому объекту геттер и сеттер?

```js
'use strict';

var positions = [
{
  title: 'Телепорт бытовой VZHIH-101',
  price: 10000,
  discount: 7,
  available: 3
},
{
  title: 'Ховерборд Mattel 2016',
  price: 9200,
  discount: 4,
  available: 14
},
{
  title: 'Меч световой FORCE (синий луч)',
  price: 57000,
  discount: 0,
  available: 1
}
];



// exercise - 2
console.log('//==========================\\');

for (let i = 0; i < positions.length; i++) {
  positions[i].finalPrice = 'new val';
}

console.log(positions);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте метод [Object.defineProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty), если правильно понял суть задачи, то должно получится как-то так:

```js
'use strict';

var positions = [
{
  title: 'Телепорт бытовой VZHIH-101',
  price: 10000,
  discount: 7,
  available: 3
},
{
  title: 'Ховерборд Mattel 2016',
  price: 9200,
  discount: 4,
  available: 14
},
{
  title: 'Меч световой FORCE (синий луч)',
  price: 57000,
  discount: 0,
  available: 1
}
];

// exercise - 2
console.log('//==========================\\');

for (let i = 0; i < positions.length; i++) {
  Object.defineProperty(positions[i], 'finalPrice', {
    enumerable: true,
    get() {
      return this.price * (100 - this.discount) / 100;
    },
    set(newFinalPrice) {
      this.price = newFinalPrice / (100 - this.discount) * 100;
    }
  });

}

console.log(positions);
```